# Finding Number of Numbers

Tags: python

A number X is such that it can be expressed as a + b + c + d + e + f = X where a,b,c,d,e and f are any six factors of X. how many numbers below 1400 have this property ??

I tried to write the code in python but unable to reach it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code you have so far.

Comment: I recommend you break up your task into several subtasks: (1) find all factors of a number, (2) check if the factors of a number sum up to the number, (3) perform previous two steps on all numbers between 1 an 1399.

Comment: It seems like a college task or something like that, so please provide at least a reasoning on how you would approach the problem. Codewise, are you allowed to use libraries or not?

Comment: Are duplicates like a=b allowed?

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import combinations

def getFactors(num: int) -> List[int]:
    factors = []
    for i in range(1, num + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
    return factors

def findNumbers(upperlimit: int) -> int:
    count = 0
    for num in range(1, upperlimit + 1):
        factors = getFactors(num)
        if len(factors) >= 6:
            for comb in combinations(factors, 6):
                if sum(comb) == num:
                    count += 1
                    break  
    return count
```

1. Iterate through numbers from 1 to upperlimit.
2. For each number, find all of its factors.
3. Generate all possible combinations of 6 factors from the list of factors.
4. Check if the sum of any combination equals to the number.
5. Count the numbers that satisfy this property.

Comment: Welcome to [so].